# How to asynchronously service multiple QBWC clients with Node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, quickbooks, qbwc

The idea is to implement a QBWC web service using Node.js which can serve multiple incoming requests in an asynchronous fashion. Currently I am looking into [qbws](https://github.com/johnballantyne/qbws/) which is a Node.js web service for QuickBooks Desktop Web Connector. Any ideas on how I can extend this to support an asynchronous architecture for the service methods?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It's on my wishlist to modify qbws to use asynchronous callbacks for each method, but I don't currently have a suitable testing environment to make sure it's working properly. I've been working on resolving that, but for now you'll need to modify it to suit your needs. It shouldn't be that difficult though; just feel free to open up an issue on GitHub if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: @JohnB would you have some demo code on how the qbws work?

Comment: @WABBIT0111 the code on GitHub is functional, check the [Usage section](https://github.com/johnballantyne/qbws#usage). If you have any questions about it, feel free to open up an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [soap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap) module [supports asynchronous function calls](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap#soap-listen-server-path-services-wsdl-create-a-new-soap-server-that-listens-on-path-and-provides-services) which makes this easy to do. To use the same template as [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32337847/1832306), here's how you'd do that:

```
var soap = require('soap');

var yourService = {
    QBWebConnectorSvc: {
        QBWebConnectorSvcSoap: {
            serverVersion: function (args, callback) {

                // serverVersion code here

                callback({
                    serverVersionResult: { string: retVal }
                });
            },
            clientVersion: function (args, callback) {

                //clientVersion code here

                callback({
                    clientVersionResult: { string: retVal }
                });
            },

            // and all other service functions required by QBWC

        }
    }
};
```

There are two differences:

1. Each method signature has an additional `callback` parameter
2. There is no `return`, that's handled by `callback()` instead.

I don't currently have a suitable environment to test this, but I created [a client to imitate QuickBooks Web Connector](https://github.com/johnballantyne/qbwc) and it worked fine. Converting the qbws methods to asynchronous allowed it to service multiple clients simultaneously (including one legitimate QBWC client).

Comment: This is awesome!..tested with multiple actual QBWC clients.. working fine with the asynchronous calls to other servers..Thanks a tonne!

Comment: @newbie: Do you have an example code in github or open source that i can take a look? i am also developing a similar app to integrate with QuickBooks Desktop.

Comment: @newbie if you have this code snippet on Github , then provide the link so that we will have a look, I'm also working on the same thing.